# Webpack + Vuejs + GSAP issue

Tags: webpack, vue.js, gsap

I got this issue when install `GSAP` via `npm` 
I'm using basic `webpack-vuecli` template from `github`

error is:

> __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_gsap___default.a.to is not a function

in my component I import it

```
  import TweenMax from 'gsap';
```

and then using it in methods something like this

```
 typeText() {
    TweenMax.to('#header-line-1', 1, { x: 500 });
  }
```

here is my webpack config file

```
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
   const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

const createLintingRule = () => ({
  test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  enforce: 'pre',
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
  options: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
    emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
  }
})

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },
  module: {
rules: [
  ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
  {
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader',
    options: vueLoaderConfig
  },
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
  },
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

below there are other rules i think they're not neccesary to my question

Answer (score 0):

TweenMax is not the default export.

This should work:

```
import { TweenMax } from 'gsap/all'
const anim = [TweenMax] // eslint-disable-line (prevent tree shake)
```